# NULL handling in dbcontext and objectcontext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, dbcontext, objectcontext

I have this simple LINQ query

```
from e in Employees 
where e.DesignationID !=558
select e
```

Here `DesignationID` is a nullable field:

In `objectcontext` the query is translated to:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[EmployeeID] AS [EmployeeID], 
[Extent1].[EmployeeCode] AS [EmployeeCode], 
[Extent1].[EmployeeName] AS [EmployeeName],
[Extent1].[DesignationID] AS [DesignationID] 
FROM [dbo].[setupEmployees] AS [Extent1]
WHERE 558 <> [Extent1].[DesignationID]
```

While the same query in `dbcontext` it is translated to:

```
 SELECT 
    [Extent1].[EmployeeID] AS [EmployeeID], 
    [Extent1].[EmployeeCode] AS [EmployeeCode], 
    [Extent1].[EmployeeName] AS [EmployeeName],
    [Extent1].[DesignationID] AS [DesignationID] 
    FROM [dbo].[setupEmployees] AS [Extent1]
 WHERE  NOT ((558 = [Extent1].[DesignationID]) AND ([Extent1].[DesignationID] IS NOT NULL))
```

Why does `objectcontext` handle NULL differently than `dbcontext`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is configurable, so most likely it's a matter of a different default (I don't know why the default is different).

The control is provided by the [DbContextConfiguration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextConfiguration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.6);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) property:

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether database null semantics are exhibited when comparing two operands, both of which are potentially nullable. **The default value is false**. For example (operand1 == operand2) will be translated as: (operand1 = operand2) if UseDatabaseNullSemantics is true, respectively (((operand1 = operand2) AND (NOT (operand1 IS NULL OR operand2 IS NULL))) OR ((operand1 IS NULL) AND (operand2 IS NULL))) if UseDatabaseNullSemantics is false.

To get the same translation as in your first example, you should set it to `true` (for instance inside your db context constructor):

```
public YourDbContext()
{
    // ...
    this.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = true;
}
```